# Windows 10 - log all process exits _with CPU time used_

Tags: windows-10, process, cpu-usage

I want to make a log of all processes run under the my login that lists all processes run and the total CPU used by that process.

Yes, I know about Audit Process Tracking, but the terminate event does not include CPU time.

This is a performance monitoring type question. I'm trying to monitor an app proted from Unix that spins off literally hundreds of child processes in performing its work. I want to capture the total CPU time including those child processes.

THanks

Answer (score 0):

The Task Manager can show cumulative CPU hours in the "App history" tab.
Use "Delete usage history" before starting.
However, this history option is a bit strange and might not work for you.

[image]

A product which might do the job is
[Process Lasso Pro](https://bitsum.com/).
It has a [Logging](https://bitsum.com/logging/) function which might be
what you are looking for.
However, it's unclear whether this function is available in the free version.

[image]